# Error Dictionary Item 'DataTemplate' must have a Key attribute while set x:DataType="BitmapImage"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to implement sample Universal Windows Platform Application for displaying Number of images in a Grid,when i frame images sources into Item-panel then build the solution getting this error  "Error Dictionary Item 'Data Template' must have a Key attribute"
Please any one suggest some thing or help me.

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ImgList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    var image = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(
                               new Uri(
                                   "https://canaryappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/dummy-container/food"+i+"_tn.jpg"))
    };
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    ImgList.Add(image.Source as BitmapImage);
    image.Source = null;
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImgList2}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="200"
                       Height="100"
                       Source="{x:Bind }"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Remove the "x:" namespace prefix from the DataType attribute of your DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `DataTemplate` in `ItemsControl.Resources`. To make it work as a template for your items, you have to declare it in `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`.